# Login Form PHP MySqli

Tags: php, forms, authentication

So I have this code and it's not working... can you help me out?

This is the Login Form ->

```
 <form name="login" action="entrar.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label>E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </fieldset>
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
              <a href="recuperar.html">Recuperar a Password</a>
        </form>
```

This is checking the login->

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $lig=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dompingasbd");
        if($lig->connect_error==NULL){
            $inst=$lig->prepare("SELECT password FROM cliente WHERE email=?");
            $inst->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);
            $inst->execute();
            $inst->bind_result($hashBD);
            if($inst->fetch()==TRUE &&
                               password_verify($_POST['password'], $hashBD)==TRUE){
                $_SESSION['utilizador']=$_POST['email'];
                echo "<p>Welcome!!!</p>";
            }
            else{
                session_destroy();
                echo "<p>Wrong!</p>";   
            }
            $inst->close();             
            $lig->close();    
        }
        else echo "<p>Por favor efetue o <a href='Login.php'>login</a></p>";
    }
    else echo "<p>Por favor efetue o <a href='Login.php'>login</a></p>";
    ?>
```

It's always returning the wrong echo... What do you think is wrong? Thank You

Comment: is it producing an error displayed on the page? What is it returning?

Comment: When you `echo $hashBD;` what does it output, and if you just manually put that in `password_verify` on it's own with the posted password, does it return true?

Comment: its returning the echo"<p>Wrong!</p>" when I login with exact same credentials as the database

Comment: u login with the hashed password?

Comment: Just noticed you are not starting your session

Comment: sry I forgot to put that part of the code but I have the session started in the beggining of the page

Comment: @Chino. Echo out the `$hashBD` value, then verify that against the password manually, without any other code. Does this return true?

Comment: ok, when echo $hashBD it returns the password that I have in my database @JamieBicknell

Comment: then replace your `$_POST['password']` with $hashBD value and see if it return true like @JamieBicknell said

Answer (score 0):

Try using while($inst->fetch()) instead of checking if fetch() returns true.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $lig=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dompingasbd");
    if($lig->connect_error==NULL){
        $inst=$lig->prepare("SELECT password FROM cliente WHERE email=?");
        $inst->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);
        $inst->execute();
        $inst->bind_result($hashBD);
        while($inst->fetch()) {
            if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $hashBD)) {
                $_SESSION['utilizador']=$_POST['email'];
                echo "<p>Welcome!!!</p>";
            }
            else {
                session_destroy();
                echo "<p>Wrong!</p>";  
            }
        }
        $inst->close();             
        $lig->close();    
    }
    else echo "<p>Por favor efetue o <a href='Login.php'>login</a></p>";
}
else echo "<p>Por favor efetue o <a href='Login.php'>login</a></p>";
?>
```

Comment: no explanation? like what did u fix for what error?

Comment: Replaced the part between $inst->bind_result($hashBD); and $inst->close();

Comment: i think your $stmt is actually $inst.